# Mongoid: Order by field and skip N records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid, database

I have a collection with the following data:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("516b969beceaed363a000027"),
  "user" : "276",
  "item" : "796",
  "rating" : 1,
}
```

I want to order by `user` and then within each user, I want to skip the first 10 records, and only return the other records. If a user doesn't have 10 records, it should return nothing. And I also need this the other way round: Order by user and only return the first 10 records. If a user doesn't have 10 records, it should return for example 6 records.

I have no idea how to do this in Mongoid, without invoking a ruby script. Any ideas?

Comment: There is no way to do this in aggregation framework nor in simple query.  You can do it using map-reduce only.

Answer (score 6):

Let's say you have defined a model that is mapped to this collection:

```
class MyModel
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :user, type: String
  field :item, type: String
  field :rating, type: Integer
end
```

Then the queries you are looking for are quite simple:

```
#  I want to order by user and then within each user, I want to skip the first 10 records, and only return the other records
MyModel.asc(:user).skip(10)

#  Order by user and only return the first 10 records. If a user doesn't have 10 records, it should return for example 6 records
MyModel.asc(:user).limit(10)
```

Note both queries return Mongoid `Criteria` object. If you need the actual array - call `to_a` on the result.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to limit the overall query, which will only skip 10 records from ALL records. I want to skip/limit 10 records from each user

Comment: You won't be able to achieve that using single MongoDB query/aggregation statement. And Mongoid doesn't provide simplified DSL for such tasks. You will have to use either Ruby or Javascript Mongo API for that.